# On the semiboundedness of Schrödinger operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is the Schrödinger operator $$-\Delta+V,$$
bounded from bellow? For example, I would like to analyze the case where V is $L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, but what about other situations, are there general results?

Comment: There are a family of Schrodinger-type operators $H=- \sum_k \partial_k^2 - V$ that are *semi-bounded* below

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, but I'm looking for an example of such a family.